# How to constrain 2 ui views of unequal height and works in different orientations

Tags: ios, constraints

I have 2 UI views which will act as containers for controls. The height of the top UI view needs to be larger than the bottom UI view. For example, for the iPhone 8 the total screen height is 667. The top view's height will be 475, and the bottom view's height will be 192. For both views the width is equal to the storyboard.

I first constrained the leading, top and trailing edges to the storyboard for the top UI view (all set to 0). I then constrained the bottom edge to the bottom UI view (also 0).

I then repeated the process for the bottom view except I changed the top constraint to constrain its self to the top UI view (set to 0) and the bottom constraint to the bottom of the storyboard (0).

After doing so I received complaints that the two views are vertically ambiguous. It obviously needed one of the 2 views to have an explicit height set. So I constrained the height of the bottom view to 192.

Now these dimensions work when the phone is vertically orientated. But, when I horizontally orient the phone the bottom UI view goes outside of the storyboard bounds and all of the constraints I had set up turn red.

The easiest way I could think of to solve this would be to set both views height to be a percentage of the storyboards height. But I'm unsure if there is anyway to do with this in IB.

This is what I would like the views to look like in either orientation.
How can I accomplish this? Is this even possible in IB?

[image: Vertically Orientated]
[image: Horizontally Orientated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you solving this problem with a stack view.

---

- Just select the two views and embed them in a stackView. (you will find this option under "Editor" - > "Embed In" -> "StackView")

[image]

- Then set the height of the red view (bigger view) in proportion to the height of the "StackView". (I set the multiplier to 0.71 of StackView Height)

[image]

- Pin top-bottom-leading-trailing of "StackView" to "SuperView".
- Done.

[image]

[image]

note- Also make sure that the stackView's 'axis' are vertical and 'alignment' and 'Distribution' both are set to fill. But the chances are that you wont have to set them manually as these are the default configurations.

Comment: This solution worked best for my needs. I was having issues with XCode crashing trying to use @andrehungaro solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the constraints to a percentage value by using Aspect Ratio Constraints.

Then you set the proportions between the items involved in the constraint. In you case specifically, you can set:

TopView.Height equals to ContainerView.Height with a multiplier of 0.7
and BottomView.Height equals to ContainerView.Height with a multiplier of 0.3.

You can set them in Storyboard:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can use size classes and add constraint for each sizeClass compact/regular width/height combination

[image]

[image]

[image]